# Enter a sequence of integers ending with the number 0

Tags: vector

a problem with a std::sort
`#include 
#include

```
int main() {
std::vector <int> sequence;
int num;
while (true) {
    std::cin >> num;
    if (num == 0) {
        break;
    }
    sequence.push_back(num);
}

if (sequence.size() < 2) {
    std::cout << "No second largest element" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::sort(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), std::greater<int>());
    std::cout << sequence[1] << std::endl;
}

return 0;
}`
```

I have a task on c++. The sequence consists of various natural numbers and ends with the number 0. Determine the value of the second largest element in this sequence, that is, the element that will be the largest if the largest element is removed from the sequence.
The numbers following the number 0 do not need to be read.
Input format:

A sequence of integers ending in the number 0 is entered (the number 0 itself is not included in the sequence). The values of the numbers do not exceed 109.
Output format:

Print the answer to the problem.
I don't know why do the compiler shows me an error.>